# creating different style CTA button in the menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, buttons

I'm wondering if there is a possible way to create two different CTA button style in the same menu in WordPress [image: like this example]

I've tried something like that by creating two menu href and add two different [btn] style at the css, but the problem was both buttons have the same style and color if there is a possible way to escape style on the menu links ?

attached is my walker code

```
<?php
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
$object      = $item->object;
$type        = $item->type;
$title       = $item->title;
$description = $item->description;
$permalink   = $item->url;

$active_class = '';
if( in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) {
    $active_class = 'active';
}

$dropdown_class = '';
$dropdown_link_class = '';
if( $args->walker->has_children && $depth == 0 ) {
    $dropdown_class = 'dropdown';
    $dropdown_link_class = 'dropdown-toggle';
}

 $output .= "<li class='nav-item $active_class $dropdown_class " .  implode(" ", $item->classes) . "'>";

if( $args->walker->has_children && $depth == 0 ) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url($permalink) . '" class="nav-link ' . 
 $dropdown_link_class . '" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
 expanded="false">';
}
else {
    $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url($permalink) . '" class="">';
}

$output .= $title;

if( $description != '' && $depth == 0 ) {
    $output .= '<small class="description">' . $description . '</small>';
}

  $output .= '</a>';
 }

 function start_lvl( &$output, $depth=0, $args = array() ){
$submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
$output .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu $submenu depth_$depth'>";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you add a class that is the permalink for example?

ie

```
$output .= "<li class='nav-item $active_class $dropdown_class " .  implode(" ", $item->classes) . "'>";
```

(this line is strange first because it's going to output "nav item $active_class $dropdown_class"...is that what you want?)

but all the same it COULD be

```
$output .= "<li class='nav-item $active_class $dropdown_class " .  implode(" ", $item->classes) . " " . $permalink ."'>";
```

Then call that class in your css

```
li .menu-permalink {
  background-color:blue;
}
li .menu-permalink2 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

you can apply the `$permalink` to whatever you like (ie li or a etc) and then change the css as needed.

Comment: sure this is not what i want, i'm editing a previous theme and i'm not the professional to understand all those codes, i tried your editing but it dosnt work, still the same

Comment: provide a link to your site.

Comment: sorry, still on the localhost xampp server, what do you want to look for exactly so i can upload the files or get you a copy of its content